# jQuery move background to follow element positioned using CSS Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got an application where I'm moving an image around the page using **CSS3 Animations** the idea is you click a button and the next animation runs and this way the "sprite" moves around a map.

However on mobile I was asked to keep the size of the map the same as desktop but instead *move the map instead of the sprite*, my question is how can I make that work?

My current *(really early)* code looks like this:

```
$(document).on("boatAnimationStarted", function(event) {
    window.isAnimating = true;
    var boatElement = $("#boat-sprite");
    var backgroundElement = $("#background");
    var backgroundWidth = backgroundElement.width();
    var backgroundHeight = backgroundElement.height();
    var windowSize = { width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height() };
    var originalOffset = boatElement.offset();

    window.animationInterval = setInterval(function() {
        var boatOffset = boatElement.offset();
        var working = {
          top: originalOffset.top - (boatOffset.top / 2),
          left: originalOffset.left - (boatOffset.left / 2),
        }

        $("#background").offset(working);
    }, 10);
});
```

This does manage to move it somewhat but it doesn't seem to be exact and isn't really accounting for the offset of the *#background* element when it changes position.
So I'm guessing I should do everything relative to the Background image *(which is around 1200w X 421h)*

So to do that you would do something like this i'm guessing

```
var relativeOffset = {
 top: boatOffset.top - backgroundElement.offset().top,
 left: boatOffset.left - backgroundElement.offset().left
}
```

And I would in theory get the offsets of the sprite relative to the large background image as opposed to the mobile viewport. But then how would I go about moving the background?
Sorry if it's a simple question but it's the first time I've ever had to work with this kind of stuff so I'm a bit confused.